# Parallax Image Sizing Issue

Tags: html, wordpress, image, parallax

I am trying to replace the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OllW.jpg (wont let me upload it to here for some reason) with another image but whenever I do it it just seems to make the background white and not actually do anything. 
The way I change them is by uploading the image to the WordPress media library and replacing the image name with the other image name.

**My Questions:**

Am I doing something wrong when trying to upload?

Is my image sized wrong?

(I'm running WordPress on academyofperformancearts.com.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Wordpress theme might have an option for simply changing that image.
Try checking Appearance -> Customize in your admin panel.

if it's not there, your theme may have some addionnal settings in the menu, check thoroughly.

third option is a plugin defining it.

If not, your image happens to be located here : https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg

So though it is not best practice with a Wordpress site, you may want to replace from here as last resort. 
And don't forget to make backup when doing such changes, it is a not a correct solution and may give squishy results.